# Python list comprehension - syntax error on "if" statement

Tags: python

I consider myself to be an intermediate on Python so it's bothering me that I cannot work out why I am having the following problem.

I am using the SQLAlchemy module. Within the `table` object there is a `column` object which is a collection:

```
table.columns
# <sqlalchemy.sql.base.ImmutableColumnCollection object>
```

Using a list comprehension, I can see the data types of all of these columns:

```
[x.type for x in user.columns]
# [Integer(), String(length=16), String(length=60), String(length=50)]
```

However, the second I put an "if" statement at the end, the statement fails with a syntax error:

```
[x.type for x in user.columns if x.type = 'Integer()']
#   File "<stdin>", line 1
#   [x.type for x in user.columns if x.type = 'Integer()']
#                                            ^
# SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What I want to know is - why? Why can I return `x.type` in my output but I can't use it to filter?

Comment: `==` instead of `=` ?

Comment: Like most programming languages, Python uses `=` for assignment and `==` for testing equality. SQL just uses one equals sign, as well as math of course, which can obviously be a source of confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
 [x.type for x in user.columns if x.type == 'Integer()']
```

because the `if` needs an operator of equality:

```
 ==
```

and not an assignement.